# How to stop Tomcat from restarting?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat7

In Spring boot application how to stop tomcat from restarting again and again when
code is changed.

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: You mean during development? Disable devtools

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml file

Answer (score 1):

This dependency is probably somewhere in your **POM.xml**:

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

It is used for exactly the behavior you are describing, '*not having to restart the server manually*' during development.

It is automatically disabled and not present in a production build.

If you don't like it just remove the dependency from your **POM.xml** and load maven changes.

There are probably also some settings in you IDE that could turn this behavior off temporarily. If you use **IntelliJ**:

- Under: `File`->`settings`->`build,execution,deployment`->`compiler`

  Turn off the building of the project automatically

**OR:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>->`registry`

  Turn off `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running`

In **Eclipse** or **Spring tool suite**:

- Under: `Project`

  Uncheck `Build Automatically`

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be because of the devtools that you added in your pom.xml.

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Just remove this dependency and update the project.

Another solution can be, if you use Eclipse or spring tool suite , you can uncheck this option

[image: SpringToolSuite]